# What is the range of the T-UGS?

Tags: battlefield-3

It seems like this gadget is able to sense enemy locations periodically even through walls (which makes it much more useful than I originally thought). How far out does it detect?

Also, the description in-game says one can avoid detection by moving slowly. What are the parameters for this? crouch+walk? Walk at some percent of max speed if using gamepad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The range seems to be about half the height of the minimap at maximum zoom (just less than the width).

As for avoiding detection, if an enemy is crouched or prone (or walking at a speed as slow or slower than crouching) then they will not show up on the minimap.

(No source for any of this, just my own observations)

Comment: what do you mean by maximum zoom? Maximum zoomed IN or maximum zoomed OUT? I'm very unclear.

Comment: @JeffAtwood As far in as you can zoom. It would be minimum zoom the other way around.

Comment: Incidentally I am not sure if the zoom levels are consistent across maps. I do know that on some maps the 2nd zoom level (2nd most zoomed in) is barely any different from the 1st level, but on other larger maps it is much more zoomed out.