# What is the maximum detection range on the T-UGS in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the range of the T-UGS?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37138/what-is-the-range-of-the-t-ugs)

Depending on my current sniping location, I usually want to place my T-UGS for max detecting efficiency.  Usually on metro I will place it below Objective B (if contested) to help the team out, but on other maps where I might be alone with no backup, placing the T-UGS can be more crucial for survival. [I am aware that crouching / prone bypasses detection]

**What is the maximum radius or range of the T-UGS?**

[image]

[Source of Picture](http://bf3blog.com/battlefield-3-t-ugs-motion-sensor/battlefield-3-tugs/)